# Regular Expression to Delete Part of Filename in JSON File

Tags: regex, json

I have a series of execution paths as a field in a json file.  Each line in the file represents a record and a line of the file is structured as follows:

```
"2596192":[{"jobID":"2596192","account":"TG-MCB110136","user":"px","pkgT":{"mkl/10.0":{"libA":  
    ["libmkl_lapack.so"],"flavor":["default"]}},"startEpoch":"1338439337","runTime":"1337","execType":"use r:binary","exec":"/work/01779/plsawle/amber/amber10/bin/sander.MPI","numNodes":"1","sha1":"1f28c333d0f1534ffd8c67c26edff917d7980e48","execEpoch":1313768808,"execModify":"Fri Aug 19 10:46:48 2011","startTime":"Wed May 30 23:42:17 2012","numCores":"16","sizeT":{"bss":"82704936","text":"5722390","data":"489580"}}],
```

As you can see, the execution path for the "exec" field is the fully qualified path; however, I would like to use a regular expression to delete the beginning of the path and just save the actual name of he executable.  For example,  instead of...

```
 "exec":"/work/01779/plsawle/amber/amber10/bin/sander.MPI"
```

I would like the field to be...

```
"exec":sander.MPI
```

Since the length of each exec value is arbitrary as are the number of "/" in the path, I am unsure of how to structure a regular expression to make this conversion.  Can someone please recommend a solution?  Thanks!

Comment: What language are you using?  There are different flavors of regex.

Comment: I am using textWrangler which uses standard grep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex will match only the executable name

```
[^/]+(?:\.\w+)?$
```

Sample use with javascript object

```
var obj = { exec : "/work/01779/plsawle/amber/amber10/bin/sander.MPI" };
var execName = obj.exec.match(/[^/]+(?:\.\w+)?$/i);
```

**EDIT**

I didn't realized you we're parsing through a full JSON file, you'll need the following Regex

```
("exec":").+?([^/]+?(?:\.\w+)?")
```

I am not familiar with textWrangler however typically you would then replace with `$1$2` or `\1\2`.

If your text editor supports Regex with lookaround (lookahead and lookbehind assertions) you could use the following Regex and replace with an empty string.

```
(?<="exec":").+?(?=[^/]+?(?:\.\w+)?")
```

Comment: I just ran the above through the json file and it did not find any matches. Plus not all the executables have the file extension.  Some are just a name,

Comment: updated to handle no extensions exec. I didn't realize you we're trying parsing a json file and replacing value.

Comment: I am not familiar with Javascript and have no clue how I could even read and write a file.  I just want to delete the beginning of the full path in the json document and resave it.

Comment: The update version works to find all the values.  Now I just need to know how to delete the beginning portion of the path.